# Exoneration of future sins

Tags: hebrews

Hebrews 10:17, NKJV (Quoting from Jeremiah 31:34) -

> Their sins and their lawless deeds I will remember no more.

Many are being led to believe that this implies exoneration of all sin, including **future** sin. Is that what this text is teaching?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange.  If you haven't done so already, check out the [site tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) and read up on how we are [a little different](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803) than most sites around the web.  ...   It isn't clear what you are asking here.  Please explain what you mean by "including future sins".

Comment: @ThaddeusB FWIW, I understood the question.

Comment: @Jas Well, I could guess the OP meant sins committed after conversion since it is phrased as (a response to) a doctrinal question, but its actual ambiguous.  If that is indeed the question, it should be phrased something like "does the author of Hebrews intend this quote to show that all sins of the believer past, present, and future are forgiven at the moment of conversion."

Comment: @ThaddeusB I guess I'm missing the alternative. What else could he be asking?

Comment: @Jas It could be a question of whether the OT promise applies to future people (i.e. Christians) as a group or future believers, rather than the future life of an already believing individual.

Answer (score 1):

### Exegesis

Jeremiah 31:34 is part of a prophecy about a "New Covenant" which would one day be instituted between God and Israel. The passage describes the nature of this New Covenant under which they would one day live:

> “But this is the covenant which I will make with the house of Israel after those days,” declares the Lord, “I will put My law within them and on their heart I will write it; and I will be their God, and they shall be My people. They will not teach again, each man his neighbor and each man his brother, saying, ‘Know the Lord,’ for they will all know Me, from the least of them to the greatest of them,” declares the Lord, . . . ***[--Jeremiah 31:33-34, NASB](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Jeremiah%2031%3A33-34&version=NASB)***

Under this New Covenant, the Israelites would have God's law within them, and would know God, and would be His people. Then comes the statement you quoted:

> . . . "**for** I will forgive their iniquity, and their sin I will remember no more."
>
> . . . **כִי** אֶסְלַח לַעָוֹנָם וּלְחַטָּאתָם לֹא אֶזְכָּר עוֹד

This statement gives the **reason** for this unusual state of things under the New Covenant: God's gracious forgiveness and forbearance. In other words, God is not simply saying "I'll make a New Covenant with you *because* I've forgiven you"; He is saying "I'll make a New Covenant with you, and being under the New Covenant will be great *in such and such a way* because I'll forgive you." So **the state of things under the New Covenant would be a state of forgiveness and forbearance.**

### Answer

What you're really wondering though is whether sins committed after the institution of the New Covenant would also be met with forgiveness and forbearance. Though the author's intent in this passage was not to address this issue, it is implicit here and elsewhere that the answer is a nuanced **"yes"**. Consider:

- The Israelites already had a holy Covenant by which they could be in right relationship with God, internalize the Law through meditation, and be "God's people". The problem they faced again and again was their inability to keep *their* side of the agreement by ceasing from sin.
- If the New Covenant were no different, also being a holy Covenant, but also depending on their ability to cease from sin, it would not have been all that exciting to this nation of people so accustomed to falling down in the area of sin.
- The "New Covenant" is presented here (and elsewhere throughout the Old Testament) as the blessed hope of Israel: one day things would be **different**; one day they would be under a **different Covenant**.
- Jeremiah's intent here was to describe *how* things would be different under the New Covenant.
- One of Jeremiah's key observations about -- and in fact, *reasons for* -- the state of things under the New Covenant was that its members would enjoy God's forgiveness and forbearance. (Finally!!)

Thus it is safe to conclude that under the New Covenant things would not be like they were under the Old Covenant. Whereas under the Old Covenant sins were met with punishment and destruction, under the New Covenant they would be met with forgiveness. So, both author and readers would have taken this to mean that if they slipped up under the New Covenant it would not be the death penalty! There would be mercy and grace and forbearance. So **yes, the passage suggests the forgiveness of future sins as well.**

---

Incidentally, it is worth noting that this does not in any way suggest that licentiousness would be tolerated under the New Covenant, or that it would be impossible for one to break the New Covenant. It merely suggests that Israel's inability to uphold the regulations of the prior Covenant would no longer be a hindrance under the New Covenant, because not only would God's law be on their hearts, but He would also show them forgiveness and forbearance.